# SharpDevelop and can not open input file "input file 'kernel32.lib' (LNK1181)"

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I am having tough time getting work with SharpDevelop. I downloaded SharpDevelop 4.0.0 on WindowsXP Service Pack 3.

I created a plain solution for WebDriver to have my hands on C# binding of WebDriver. When ever I build the solution I encounter following exception -

"cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib' (LNK1181)"

I found following post which details same problem -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2009/01/30/getting-fatal-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-kernel32-lib.aspx

And found that I indeed have entry "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\" for "installationFolder"

Is any one else also encountered this issue?

Comment: Any takers for this question?